# Ошибка изменения версии Runtime, при изменении кода в отладке

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Не заметил, когда началась эта проблема. Но когда я в debug останавливаю отладку, изменяю код проекта, и пытаюсь запустить снова, появляется предупреждение о том, что в коде присутствуют ошибки. Закрывая предупреждения в списке ошибок появляется подобная ошибка:

Ошибка  CS7038  Не удалось выдать модуль "OverTrade": Изменение версии ссылки на сборку недопустимо во время отладки: "System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" изменил версию на "7.0.0.0"